# how to get goo.gl analytics?

Tags: short-url, goo.gl

I want to get all the analytics that goo.gl has for a given short url, for example http://goo.gl/kuBJ7S

I tried the following

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=http://goo.gl/kuBJ7S&projection=FULL'
```

but I don't really get much data this way. For example, I would like to know for each  click the ip address, timestamp for the click, etc.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned data is documented here: https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/url

No, this does not include individual users' IP addresses or such. I'd imagine that would be a gross violation of privacy laws/guidelines/concerns.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to get the time-stamp for each click?

Comment: Again, what you can get is documented at the aforelinked URL. What's not in there cannot be gotten.

Comment: The goo.gl (URL shortener) analytics used to provide IP information per visitor. Not anymore though, it seems. There's nothing really untoward about it though. Pretty standard stuff.